# Where is place $content in node--product--type.tpl.php be generated and manipulated in drupal commerce?

Tags: commerce

I am a beginner of drupal commerce, I know [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce) display product with `node--product--type.tpl.php`, "`render($content)`" does this work.

I need to add a property "*monthly sales*" to each node(product display) so that I can display it in node page.

With drupal core, I can use `hook_load` and `hook_view` to display custom properties, but it seems Drupal Commerce doesn't work by this way.

Where is place the array `$content` be generated and manipulated in Drupal Commerce? Which hook can I use?

Appreciate for any help or comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, It's hook_entity_view. We can read profiles\commerce_kickstart\modules\contrib\commerce\modules\product_reference\commerce_product_reference.module for reference.